# How to save terminal displayed output to a txt file?

Tags: files, gnu-screen

I have tried with the `script` but it does not work.

```
milenko@milenko-desktop:~/MTM$ script output.txt
Script started, file is output.txt

milenko@milenko-desktop:~/MTM$ wc -l output.txt
0 output.txt
```

There are more than 4000000 lines on my screen a s a result of execution of a C code.Just part of this

```
4194282 0.166666 2.35285e-06 -56.2841 -137.299 -129.386 4 0.974001
4194283 0.166666 2.2536e-06 -56.4712 -129.67 -131.872 4 0.577388
4194284 0.166666 2.33943e-06 -56.3089 -131.649 -132.051 4 0.693404
4194285 0.166666 2.40782e-06 -56.1838 -139.678 -129.377 4 0.702479
4194286 0.166666 2.61584e-06 -55.8239 -125.733 -128.783 4 0.585886
4194287 0.166666 2.60877e-06 -55.8356 -129.239 -127.815 4 0.773082
4194288 0.166666 2.71129e-06 -55.6682 -129.591 -127.553 4 0.796556
4194289 0.166666 2.89225e-06 -55.3876 -125.257 -127.627 4 0.815006
4194290 0.166666 2.84658e-06 -55.4568 -129.576 -127.566 4 0.557463
4194291 0.166666 2.71516e-06 -55.662 -129.31 -128.904 4 0.797976
4194292 0.166666 2.56104e-06 -55.9158 -127.996 -128.422 4 0.895766
4194293 0.166666 2.6007e-06 -55.8491 -128.079 -129.663 4 0.503785
4194294 0.166666 2.40808e-06 -56.1833 -140.025 -128.88 4 0.857429
4194295 0.166666 2.33237e-06 -56.322 -126.524 -130.575 4 0.410364
4194296 0.166666 2.46136e-06 -56.0883 -135.197 -130.224 4 0.833398
4194297 0.166666 2.48021e-06 -56.0551 -134.945 -131.935 4 0.856674
4194298 0.166666 2.43826e-06 -56.1292 -128.865 -128.875 4 0.490521
4194299 0.166666 2.45184e-06 -56.1051 -126.444 -129.16 4 0.935146
4194300 0.166667 2.51457e-06 -55.9954 -141.302 -130.337 4 0.745215
4194301 0.166667 2.47265e-06 -56.0684 -133.622 -131.74 4 0.541706
4194302 0.166667 2.45156e-06 -56.1056 -128.236 -128.832 4 0.503959
4194303 0.166667 2.54703e-06 -55.9397 -127.012 -127.581 4 1.10325
4194304 0.166667 2.55029e-06 -55.9341 -132.414 -127.012 4 0.475155
```

How to save this?

If I try  `script > output.txt`

```
Script started, file is typescript
]0;milenko@milenko-desktop: ~/MTM[01;32mmilenko@milenko-desktop[00m:[01;34m~/MTM[00m$ exit
Script done, file is typescript
```

I have also tried

```
command | tee ~/outputfile.txt
```

But again

```
 wc -l outputfile.txt 
0 outputfile.txt
```

So this is not the right way.

Comment: The `script` command allows you to record the terminal session going forward - are you trying to save output that has already been displayed in your terminal?

Comment: @steeldriver Yes,exactly the output from the previous terminal session.

Comment: take a look here http://www.tecmint.com/record-and-replay-linux-terminal-session-commands-using-script/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my little secret for when I need to capture both stdout and stderr is to use **nohup**. This is a good solution when you are only interested in output, not the interaction on screen as well.

The *classic* way to capture stdout (only) and display it on screen is to use the command **tee**

```
nohup script.sh | tee merged.out
```

And if only stdout is desired

```
script.sh | tee script.out
```

Here is a quick example using the command `ls` rather than script.sh

```
xx069:~ # nohup ls | tee merged.out
nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout
bin
inst-sys
merged.out
xx069:~ # cat merged.out
bin
inst-sys
merged.out
```

And, of course, redirection such as 2>&1 to combine stdout and stderr is also possible.

Mainly, I use `script` to capture the input and output on screen. When only the output is needed I use one of `>`, `>>`, `2>&1 >`, `tee`, and `tee -a` - depending on the need. And `nohup` when I am lazy.

Answer (score 5):

if You use `script` command:

```
script history_log.txt
```

then do what ever you want and when you finish type:

```
exit
```

if you mean the output of script then redirect stdout:

```
script.sh > output.txt
```

- `>` redirect the stdout to any ware you want
- `2>` redirect the stderr
- `&>` redirect both stdout and stderr

Comment: Just to avoid confusion. You are not taking about `script` command but rather a script file written by user like `script.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [nhi](https://github.com/strang1ato/nhi). It automatically captures all potentially useful information about each executed command (as well as its output).

With `nhi` you can easily retrieve any shell session or a single command like in your case.

**Note:**

I am the creator of this tool. If you have questions, please feel free to ask.